# How to dynamically (w/o refresh) update/load a table after triggering submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, inline

I have a table that can edit table cells, after pressing 'enter' the whole page is refreshing and the table is updated. My problem is how to do it dynamically where after presssing 'enter', only the table is being loaded with new values.

I tried it with .load() event but after pressing 'enter' the whole table is gone and you need to submit again the button to show the table.

this is partly my code:

```
$('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
            if(event.which == 13){


                        $.ajax({type: "POST",
                        url: "controller/inline.php",
                        data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&rownum="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1],
                        success: function(data){
                            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');                         
                                            }
                                            });

                    $('#submit').trigger('click');
                    //$("#tblMain").load("view/section.php #tblMain"); //<--- how to combine this with trigger submit button?
            }


});
```

Comment: What it does, or doesn't do? I would recommend storing your `rownum` and `field` in the `data-*`-attributes (`<td data-rownum="13"`) and getting with `var rownum = $(this).data('rownum');`. Because if you add more classes in the future this code is not working.

Comment: after keypress enter, the td.edit is updated with the inputted value but it does not send form data to update my whole table